# Admob integration with simple-xml in Android?

Tags: android, admob, integration, simple-framework

I am having a hard time integrating an Admob banner into my game. I have used simple-xml-2.6.2.jar library because I considered it to be simple to implement into my game. Now I have a single layout file, with the correct code for publisher ID and test device:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, zzzzzzzzzzzz"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The game runs in landscape mode, and I would like tu get the ads to show as a banner at the top or bottom, but there aren't any test ads being shown, and I haven't got any ideas as to why is that.
Any help is apreciated!

Comment: Check the logcat output. What kind of messages are you seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code in xml say xml name is `adview.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/adView"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dip"/>
```

Now in your Activity load the ad.

```
 AdView adView = new AdView(this,AdSize.BANNER,"yourid");
 LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 ll.addView(adView);
 AdRequest ar = new AdRequest();
 ar.setGender(AdRequest.FEMALE);
 adView.loadAd(ar);
```

You can include this view(xml) in any of your activity from xml like this..

```
 <include layout="@layout/adview" />  // your xml
```

Comment: I see, I think this will work. As soon as I'm back home, I will mark your question as my accepted answer, after I check it out. Many thanks, will keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 possible ideas for you:

1. Delete the "zzzzzzzzzz" from the xml.

or

1. Make sure you are using SDK 3.2 or above. I recently solved a similar problem with this method.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work... thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
    </com.google.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>

AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```