# How to display google ads in Android using XML only?

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I want to place a google ad in my project. But for some reason, I don't want to use Java language for this purpose. I have already tried the `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"` attribute, but I think it is not working now. Is there any idea by which I can display ads by **using** **XML only**?

Comment: show your xml file and code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use old library of `google ads` , so that `loadAdOnCreate` will be available.

Answer (score 3):

`loadAdOnCreate` is no longer available in new SDK, you need to write java code to display your ads.

For ads integration you can check Harshad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35619757/3134215)

From [official Doc](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/wU3i7PcWWMg/AGporc2ttswJ) by 
**Amy Quispe (AdMob SDK Team)**

> loadAdOnCreate was deprecated in the Google Play Services version, so
>   you'll have to load the ad from the code.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code in xml say xml name is **adview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/adView"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="50dip"/>
```

Now in your Activity load the ad.

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this,AdSize.BANNER,"yourid");
 LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 ll.addView(adView);
 AdRequest ar = new AdRequest();
 ar.setGender(AdRequest.FEMALE);
 adView.loadAd(ar);
```

You can include this view(xml) in any of your activity from xml like this..

```
     <include layout="@layout/adview" />     // your xml
```

more detail visit here. [Admob integration with simple-xml in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440803/admob-integration-with-simple-xml-in-android)